# How Thread works in java?

Tags: java

I have written this code in Java but I can't understand why the output isn't what I expect.

Can anyone explain why Apples and Oranges are cluttered and they are not listed one by one?

```
package first_experiment;

class Orange extends Thread{

    public void run (){  
        for ( int i=1 ; i<21 ; i++)
            System.out.println( i + " - Orange");
    }
}

class Apple extends Thread{

    public void run(){
        for (int i =1 ; i <11 ; i++)
            System.out.println( i + " - Apple");
    }
}

public class one{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Thread O = new Orange();
        Thread A = new Apple();

        O.start();
        A.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you expect to happen and post your output?

Answer (score 5):

The two threads run at the same time.  It's up to the JVM to decide which order they get printed out in, and you cannot rely on the order being predictable.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 2 threads that run concurrently. The order of execution is unknown (since both have the same priority). Note that if `PrintStream#println()` is not synchronized then the output would be something like:

```
12 - - A ppOranlgee
// and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results to appear in a particular order, use one thread in a loop.

If you use multiple threads you want them to start and run in any order as much as possible.

Your threads are so short lived, they are running to completion before the other one can start.

BTW: You PC can perform 100,000,000 operations in the time it takes you to blink, and starting a new thread takes time.

Answer (score 0):

Threads run as seperate and indipendant streams of execution.  You might loop through several Apples before the first Orange gets some CPU time.  Also, if you are on a multiprocessor system, it is possible for both to be running concurently.

If you want them to coordinate their output, you would need to use wait() and notify().

Answer (score 0):

Threads in java are processes running independently when started, one line of started thread code is executed a time with no specific order of execution between threads.
The above code will display in console count - Orange and count - Apple randomly.

Answer (score -1):

The threads may start in any order but the results will be cluttered because System.out.println synchronizes the Thread access to it and as such then are executed one after another for printing.

To see truly random output, save the data in a List and then later print the contents of the List.